# Can't figure out why a jquery file is not loading!

Tags: jquery

I have a piece of PHP code that's supposed to load 3 jquery files. For some reason, I can only see 2 of them in the source. I can't figure out why - can anyone help me please?

Website: www.goinspire.com

My code:

```
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'add_my_jquery', 1 );

function add_my_jquery(){
 //Custom function to load a jquery script called smoothscroll.js that puts a smoothscroll on our site

wp_enqueue_script( 'smoothup', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/smoothscroll.js', array( 'jquery' ), '',  true );

//end

/*This part is to move the Subscribe button above the Submit button */
wp_enqueue_script( 'submitbutton', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/submitbutton.js', array( 'jquery' ), '',  true );

//include jqueryfunctions.js, for some functions (including hotel landing page filters)
wp_enqueue_script('jqueryfunctions', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jqueryfunctions.js', array('jquery'), '', true);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Update: the one that doesn't load is jqueryfunctions.js.

Thanks!

Updated code:

```
 add_filter( 'image_size_names_choose', 'custom_in_post_images' );

//END

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_jquery', 1 );

function add_my_jquery(){
 //Custom function to load a jquery script called smoothscroll.js that puts a smoothscroll on our site

wp_enqueue_script( 'smoothup', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/smoothscroll.js', array( 'jquery' ), '',  true );

//end

/*This part is to move the Subscribe button above the Submit button */
wp_enqueue_script( 'submitbutton', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/submitbutton.js', array( 'jquery' ), '',  true );

//include jqueryfunctions.js, for some functions (including hotel landing page filters)
wp_enqueue_script('customjqueryfunctions', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/customjqueryfunctions.js', array( ), '', true);
}
```

Comment: You should not be hooking into `wp_print_scripts`. Use `wp_enqueue_scripts`. Which script doesn't load?

Comment: I made that change, but it still doesn't load. The problematic one is jqueryfunctions.js

Comment: Try changing the name to something more unique than `jqueryfunctions` - also you could try to pass a blank array instead of `jquery`, since jquery should already be loaded with the previous scripts. Not 100% sure, the script is in the right place and everything looks correct.

Comment: I made those 2 changes, and still no success. See my updated code above. Thanks!

Comment: It's probably for the best that it's not loading. The code has a couple of serious issues, like triggering a print when the page is loaded, and trying to parse PHP inside the external JS file. Even if the script *did* load, it'd cause problems for you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have no clue what you're talking about, though. Which code has issues? I don't see anything about triggering a print in my code...
Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean in the js file? I put the print there to debug and see if the file loaded. I can take it out, of course.
What do you mean by the other issue?

Comment: When you're adding an external JavaScript file, it doesn't get parsed by PHP on the server, just by the browser. So this line: `url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>'` doesn't actually produce the URL to `admin-ajax.php` so it's not going to work. You can add a line to your `functions.php` to create the URL for use in JavaScript, and I see that the fitvids script has already done this so you can follow their method to create a JS object that you can use in your scripts.

Comment: what's fitvids? I basically copied this code from http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/Dynamically_Populating_Drop_Down_Fields#The_Code and am trying to change it for my needs, but I'm not completely sure that I put everything in the right place... If you could help I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: Sorry - wrong link! I meant this one: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/83506/gravity-forms-use-previous-dropdown-choice-as-variable-in-gform-pre-render/136192#136192